# Selenium - несколько инстансов браузера в паралели

Tags: selenium

Возможно ли запустить несколько инстансов браузера в паралели?

Есть у меня программа, которая делает некую работу в браузере. я хотел бы запустить несколько инстансов даной программы. Но как только вторая программа начинает работу, первая теряет соединение с браузером т.к. вторая забирает контроль над драйвером.

Проблем с созданием нескольких инстансов браузера внутри одной программы нету.

Comment: это потому что порт один. нужно порты разные указывать для связи

Comment: @vitidev ,по логике, если выставлен порт 0 то он должен выбирать рандомный свободный порт. Я пробовал даже сам вручную искать свободный порт и ставить через firefoxProfile.SetPreference("webdriver_firefox_port", port); Все то же самое....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно возможно.

Данный код запускает 3 файрфокса, кладет их в лист, с которым в последующем можно будет работать.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com");
      list.add(driver);
  }
  //some logic
  for (WebDriver d: list) {
      d.quit();
  }
```

Comment: А с несколькими инстансами программы с даным кодом запустится? :) У меня нету проблем запустить несколько инстансов браузера под одной программой, у меня проблемы запустить несколько инстансов браузера под разными программами (та хоть одна и та же запущеная 2 раза).

Comment: Конечно запуститься. Только если вы хотите работать параллельно, то и запускать надо будет так же параллельно